# How to manually download a streaming video (Firefox)

Tags: browser, video-streaming

How do I manually download a streaming video (I use Firefox). I don't wanna use any add-ons or any 3 rd party software or anything else. I just want to save my streaming videos manually. How can I do this ?

Comment: Cache files (video files), are they deleted once the tab is closed ?

Answer (score 3):

A pitty, because DownloadHelper is absolutely great for this.

It's actually (typically C:, but can be whatever) C:\Users\whichever_your_user\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\which_ever_your_profile.default\Cache

"whichever your profile" is a random like string (ie: "iufrweriowej") , and for you to "guess" it, I recommend you just go to C:\Users\whichever_your_user\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\  , so there you will see which is the exact profile name.

"whichever_your_user" is Harry, Joe, or whoever is the user of your windows.

There, if you set the folder view as "details", you will see as well the size. A youtube video, even if small, is going to be of several MBs of size, so it's easy to spot. You can just copy and paste one of the latest, biggest files, if you do it inmediately, (and you order by date modified) , place somewhere else, and in the case of youtube and many streaming videos, just rename to have .flv extension. To playback an flv you totally need an external player, [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is a very good one, and also serves as a general many-formats video player.

Edit: In older Windowses can be : C:\Documents and Settings\your user\Local Settings\
Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\

Comment: I have Download Helper but for some reason it says there are no active streaming video !!

Comment: Not much clues about that one... But one thing I'd try would be to ctrl + f5 (reload) then right click on Download Helper bottom right corner icon, and see if there are videos there listed now, maybe download the one which is in bold...It sometimes happens if too much time passed, maybe is the cache or sth. Try this time doing it fast after refreshing. If just you installed it, you might have needed to restart Firefox first. Anyway, grabbing it from the cache, when possible, has its advantages, too.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure. I just use Video Download helper for firefox. I remember digging around

***\user\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\2uvhpjia.default\Cache*** and being able to open most the vid files up in vlc.

Comment: I can't find a folder named Cache !!

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
about:cache
```

in your address bar and investigate the relevant paths by clicking on "List Cache Entries" (Your cache directory is given on that screen). Note that it is not guaranteed that any streaming video would be saved in your cache folder. It works for some sites, but not for the others. You may need the help of 3rd party addons or applications.

Answer (score 0):

Go to chrome, click on developers tools and then click on network. Keep this window aside and open the streaming video. In the network's column you will see a video downloading very fast (in the cache). Copy the link address of that video and open in some other browser. Moment you press enter, it will give you two options, save/open. Click on save and enjoy.....